# MySQL if(cond, a, b) inconsistent when using memory table?

Tags: mysql

I am getting some inconsistent results querying a table in MySQL. I have stripped down the code as far as possible for purpose of demonstration.

```
drop table if exists numberfill;
create table numberfill (
    id INT not null primary key auto_increment
) Engine=MEMORY;

drop procedure if exists populate;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE populate(numberRows INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT;
    SET counter = 1;
    WHILE counter <= numberRows DO
        INSERT INTO
            numberfill
        SELECT
            counter;
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

start transaction;
call populate(5000);
commit;

select if(a = 1, 5, 0), if(a = 1, 0, 5)
from (select cast(round(rand()) as unsigned) as a from numberfill) k;
```

It seems that if I do not select from numberfill, the query gives consistent results. However, when I select from the numberfill table I get mixed results. Some rows give 0, 0 and others give 5,5, and others give 5, 0 or 0, 5.

Can anyone spot why this is the case? Is it a MySQL problem or am I doing something that causes undefined behavior? I'm thinking it might have something to do with rand() producing a float.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but note for reference that `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` have no impact on `MEMORY` tables, which are not transactional tables.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs when you reference `a` more than once. Apparently MySql (v 5.7) decides to re-evaluate `a` according to its definition, i.e. it executes `rand()` again to retrieve the value for `a`.

It is not related to the Memory option, nor to the `if` function. The following query will return two different values in each row:

```
select a, a
from (select rand() as a from numberfill) k
```

You can avoid this by assigning `rand()` to a variable, and select that variable for the column alias `a`:

```
select a, a
from (select @a:=rand() as a from numberfill) k
```

That query will always return records where the two values are the same.

Another way to force the evaluation to be materialised is to set a limit to the inner query (with a value higher than the number of rows in `numberfill`):

```
select a, a
from (select rand() as a from numberfill limit 9999999999) k
```

See also [Bug #86624, Subquery's `RAND()` column re-evaluated at every reference](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86624).

Comment: Does MySQL guarantee order of evaluation of columns? In other words, is it guaranteed that @a:=rand() will be evaluated before @a as a?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any guarantee of evaluation order, but I in my experience I have never seen it evaluate in a different order.

Comment: Actually, I can just do `select if(a = 1, 5, 0), if(a = 1, 0, 5)
from (select (@a := randBool()) as a from numberfill) k;`

Comment: Indeed that will make the order of evaluation irrelevant. You can also add a limit to the sub query, and not use a variable. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

That you get mixtures of `5, 0` and `0, 5` makes perfect sense. You are filling a table with 5,000 numbers. The subquery is then assigning a random number -- 0 or 1 -- to each of the rows. This should be materialized, so the value is set.

As such, it should not be possible to get `0, 0` or `5, 5` with your logic.

The more recent versions of MySQL might figure out that materializing the subquery is not necessary -- and they might evaluate the `rand()` condition twice. If you are getting `0, 0` or `5, 5`, then that might be the case.

Comment: Yeah, I am getting 0,0 and 5,5. So essentially what you're saying is that MySQL is doing some optimization which is erroneously choosing different values for 'a' on each row. I suppose I'll just have to attack this another way.

Comment: @ChantryCargill . . . Two suggestions.  Try putting the `rand()` expression in a view.  Try a second layer of subqueries.  The latter may force MySQL to materialize the intermediate result.